# UITableView never calls tableView:shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath: on its delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimenucontroller, uitableview

I'm creating and displaying an instance of `UITableView`. The delegate (which is actually my subclass of `UITableView`) never receives any of the following selectors:

- `tableView:shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:`
- `tableView:canPerformAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:`
- `tableView:performAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:`

even though the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) specifically states, for example, under the discussion of `tableView:shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:`

> If the user tap-holds a certain row in the table view, this method
>   (if implemented) is invoked first. Return NO if the editing menu
>   shouldn’t be shown—for example, the cell corresponding to the row
>   contains content that shouldn’t be copied or pasted over.

Other tutorials also document this shortcut for displaying the `UIMenuController` in table views. Why isn't this working as documented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it isn't currently documented (I'm submitting a documentation update, but who knows when/if it will be posted), the UITableViewDelegate methods:

- tableView:shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:
- tableView:canPerformAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:
- tableView:performAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:

are only called if your table view instance is managed by an instance of UITableViewController. A standalone table view **will not have these methods invoked.**

If your table view isn't connected to a table view controller, then you'll need to display the UIMenuController manually from long tap listeners (to duplicate the standard system functionality) on each table view cell.

Comment: I tried to implement what you have suggested. Please check my question and let me know if there is anything missing or I am doing something wrong

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402641/uimenucontroller-on-uitableview-does-not-show-up-in-spite-of-all-methods

Comment: This is not true, all you need is a UITableViewDelegate that implements all 3 methods.

Comment: @Paludis If this has changed in iOS 7, then possibly so. However, I can most definitely say that it was true prior. If a table view were standalone in a UIViewController rather than a UITableViewController, those three methods are not called on the table view's delegate.

Comment: They are called on the table view's delegate if the delegate is non-nil.  I have just implemented them on a table view controller. The key is all three of the methods have to be implemented and if one of them is missing, it won't show up.

Comment: At least in iOS 6 when this was tested, @vinnybad, that was only true if your table view was contained in a UITableViewController.